# Creating collections in mongoose dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to create 50 collections that are based on the same Schema. I have exported the schema, imported it in the reveler file and now I am running a for loop that should just create the schema.
I have imported the schema as tokenSchema and running this in the for loop:

```
mongoose.model(array[i].name, tokenSchema);
```

But when I run it no collections are added (I'm sure that the loop enters this scope as I console log it.

Comment: have you connected the model?

Comment: collection will be added the first time you save.

Comment: If by *no collections are added* you mean no collections are created in db then i guess you need to insert some documents in order to create it.

Comment: What is the code that you are using to actually write the data to mongo? The code snippet that you entered doesn't do that FYI.